# Single JavaConfig class for multiple beans of same type with dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

Would it be possible to convert this config to a single @Configuration class? I need to pick the values for Car from property files

```
<bean name="VW" class="com.app.car">
    <property name="cost" value="${vw.cost}"/>
    <property name="power" value="${vw.power}"/>
</bean>

<bean name="Merc" class="com.app.car">
    <property name="cost" value="${merc.cost}"/>
    <property name="power" value="${merc.power}"/>
</bean>

<bean name="FirstCar" class="com.app.cart">
    <property name="car" ref="VW"/>
</bean>

<bean name="SecondCar" class="com.app.cart">
    <property name="car" ref="Merc"/>
</bean>
```

I know we can define different classes fro VW and Marc and then refer @Autowire them to a parent @Configuration class. Wondering if there is a solution involving defining all these beans in a single class. I tried using @Value for parameters for devAppConfig as below

```
vw(@Value("vw.cost") String cost, @Value("vw.power") String power)

merc(@Value("merc.cost") String merc, @Value("merc.power") String power)
```

But these methods have input parameters.  Having 2 different objects of the same type that need to be instantiated with different property values  and injected as dependencies is the goal

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Profiles, so you can have a property file o bean for each enviroment.

> Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application
>   configuration and make it only available in certain environments. Any
>   @Component or @Configuration can be marked with @Profile to limit when
>   it is loaded You can see more here
>   http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to be able to connect to multiple environments. Spring profiles does not meet my requirement in that case

Comment: I don't undertand well. Do you need to connect to dev and test at the same time ?

Comment: That's right. I need to connect to 2 different instances at the same time.

Comment: At this time you have your beans working with an XML file and you want to   migrate to configuration class ? if it is the case you can use the @configuration class and the bean instances with @Bean(name = "devAppConfig")
  public com.app.config devAppConfig() {
    return new com.app.config().....
  }

Comment: I probably should have been more detailed in my explanation. I have updated the problem statement. I think dev and test just threw off the context of what I am trying to achieve. My key problem is to be able to load the 'merc' and 'vw' which are of the same type with different property values in the 'Environment'

Comment: I don't undertand the problem, I ask you the same question. Do you have everything working with XML configuration ? What I understand is that you  want to have 2 instances of the Car class, and you have the values of the of these cars in a property file and you have everything working fine with the xml configuration and you want to use a configuration class instead. I think you can define your instances with @Bean(name = "vw") public Car vw() { Car c =  new Car(); c.setCost(env.getProperty("vw.cost")) }